# Help with \sidepar and position - with MVC

Tags: captions, memoir

I have a problem with a `sidepar` in the `memoir` class. I do not get the wanted result as i am unable to control the position, caption keeps aligning to the bottom line of the figure?.
FYI the result is the same for a text block...

I would like the output to have the exact look as here:

[image]

At least placement should be decided based on even and odd pages, and not pass through margins. I have tried a solution posted here on TeX.SE. It works, but not with out issues for instance larger space between text block and `sidepar` most importantly caption does not adhere to the top of the figure -  any suggestion as to how this look could be obtained would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,showtrims,a4paper,twoside]{memoir} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\sideparmargin{outer}
\settrimmedsize{24cm}{17cm}{*} 
\setlrmarginsandblock{32.125mm}{*}{0.9} 
\setulmarginsandblock{32.125mm}{*}{*} 
\setmarginnotes{0.2\foremargin}{0.7\foremargin}{\onelineskip}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 

\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]



\lipsum[1-4]
\sidepar {This is text in the sidecaption it is sould follow the margin set on even and odd pages}

%remove comment and add a figure (tex.pdf) to  your directory
%\begin{figure}[t]
%\sidepar {This is text in the sidecaption it is sould follow the margin set on even and odd pages}
%\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tex.pdf}
%\label{fig:tex}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result of MVC:
[image]

UPDATE - Result with suggestion from @egreg 
it´s not quite perfect.. - is there an alternative method that would eliminate the need for adjustments?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you simply need side captions with `memoir`, you can use the `sidecaption` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,showtrims,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\setsidecappos{t}
\setlength\sidecapwidth{80pt}
\sidecapmargin{outer}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{figure}[t]
 \begin{sidecaption}{This is text in the sidecaption it is sould follow the margin set on even and odd pages}[fig:tex1]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.9\textheight]{example-image-a}
 \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[t]
 \begin{sidecaption}{This is text in the sidecaption it is sould follow the margin set on even and odd pages}[fig:tex2]
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=.9\textheight]{example-image-b}
 \end{sidecaption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the side caption to adhere to the picture, set

```
\setlength\sidecapsep{0pt}
```

and you will get

[image]

Comment: Can sidecaption be used beside a text block ?

Comment: @Strangelove Of course not. You can use `sidelegend` but I don't know how to make it recognize odd and even pages...

Comment: @Strangelove Otherwise, for text blocks, use `\marginpar` and set `\marginparsep`=`\sidecapsep` and `\marginparwidth`=`\sidecapwidth`

Answer (score 2):

`\sidepar` will always take into consideration the depth of the line which it's linked to. Try

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}x\\x\\x\\x\\z\end{tabular}%
\sidepar{This will be at the same height as z}
```

A workaround is to typeset the picture in another line and raise it, hiding the same amoung of raising.

```
\begin{figure}[tp]

\sidepar {This is text in the sidecaption it is sould follow the margin set on even
and odd pages}

\includegraphics[
  width=\textwidth,
  valign=t,
  raise=\baselineskip,
  set height=\dimexpr\height-\baselineskip,
]{example-image.pdf}%

\end{figure}
```

With `valign=t` (provided by `adjustbox`) we make the box extend only by a normal line's height above the baseline; with `raise` we shift it up for compensating the paragraph break, with `set height` we shave off the amount of raising.

[image]

A possible simplification is to use a custom command:

```
\newcommand{\sideincludegraphics}[3][]{%
  \par\sidepar{#3}\par
  \includegraphics[
    #1,
    valign=t,
    raise=\baselineskip,
    set height=\dimexpr\height-\baselineskip,
  ]{#2}\par
}
```

so the code would become

```
\begin{figure}[tp]

\sideincludegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image.pdf}
 {This is text in the sidecaption it is sould follow
  the margin set on even
  and odd pages}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Beautiful, could this be placed in a \newcommand for simplicity? - or is there alternative method with would achieve the same side caption?

Comment: @Strangelove Here it is.

Comment: do you think sidecaption could be used? - aligning to the top is easy with \setsidecappos{t}
but i am have difficulty controlling the margins, as the sidecaption does not seem to adhere to the margin

Comment: @Strangelove I don't think it would work, because it goes in the text block, not in the margins.